# positioning anchor elements and a button inside a label

Tags: html, css

Here's my login page: [image]

Sorry, i tried to post my code on jsfiddle but it messes it up big time...

Anyway...here's my html and css:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Território Levita</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/StyleSheet1.css" />   
    <script src="js/JavaScript1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <header class="headerLogin">
            <h1>Território Levita</h1>
        </header>
        <div class="boxLogin">
            <h1>Área de Login</h1>
            <label>
                <span>Usuário: </span>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtUsuario" CssClass="inputText" ></asp:TextBox>
            </label>

            <label>
                <span>Senha: </span>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSenha" TextMode="Password" CssClass="inputText"></asp:TextBox>
            </label>

            <label id="labelBtn">
                <a href="#">Cadastre-se</a>
                <a href="#">Esqueci minha senha</a>
                <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn" ID="btnLogar" Text="Entrar" />
            </label>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


* { /*Zerando margin e padding global.*/
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body { /*Estilo de body*/
    background-color: #fff;
}

.inputText { /*Zerando padding dos inputs*/
    padding: 0px;
}

.headerLogin { /*Área de login*/
    width: 95%;
    background-color: #67BCDB;
    margin: 10px auto 150px auto;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #4e707c; /*Sombra Firefox*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #4e707c; /*Sombra chrome*/
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #4e707c;
}

    .headerLogin h1 { /*Texto do cabeçalho*/
        color: #fff;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        margin-left: 20px;
        display: inline-block;
    }


.boxLogin { /*Estilo da área de login*/
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; /*Firefox*/
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; /*Chrome*/
    border-radius: 5px; /*IE*/
    border: 8px solid #eee;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #4e707c; /*Sombra Firefox*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #4e707c; /*Sombra chrome*/
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #4e707c; /*Sombra IE*/
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
}

    .boxLogin h1 { /*Estilo do cabeçalho*/
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 22px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #67BCDB;
        color: #fff;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        height: 50px;
        line-height: 50px;
    }

    .boxLogin label { /*Container dos controles*/
        display: block;
        width: 90%;
        background-color: #dbd8d8;
        margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
        -moz-border-radius: 6px; /*Firefox*/
        -webkit-border-radius: 6px; /*Chrome*/
        border-radius: 5px; /*IE*/
        padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    }

    .boxLogin span { /*Estilo do texto (usuário e senha)*/
        float: left;
        width: 60px;
        text-align: left;
        margin-left: 5px;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        font-family: 'Bitstream Vera Sans Mono';
        font-weight: normal;
    }

    .boxLogin .inputText { /*Estilo dos inputs*/
        width: 200px;
        padding: 5px;
        margin-top: 1px;
        margin-bottom: 1px;
        margin-left: 150px;
    }

    .boxLogin #labelBtn { /*Container do botão*/
        background: #fff;
        position: relative;
        text-align: right;

    }

.btn { /*Estilo do botão*/
    background-color: #E44424;
    padding: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #4e707c; /*Sombra Firefox*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #4e707c; /*Sombra chrome*/
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #4e707c;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 150px;
}

#labelBtn .btn {


}

a {
    text-decoration: none;                
}
```

As you can see, i have labels as containers for my spans and asp.textboxes...here's the thing: i'm trying to make the label with the anchors and the button inside display them as three 'blocks' with same size...like 33% each...and the button would be exactly where it is now. It is in the right position because i've set its parent label to have text-align set to right...But it wrecks my "3 blocks with same size each" plan...how can i make it happen?

And one more thing....labels or field sets for encapsulation of components?

Answer (score 0):

For your purposes, "label" in HTML 5 is just like "div", so you can add classes and id's the same way that you would for a div:

If your box width isn't dynamically adjusting, and assuming your ".boxLogin" label is 180px tall, just give each of your labels a class like ".heightSetter", and in your css add:

> .heightSetter {
>       height: 60px;
>       float: right;
>   }

This will give then all an equal height and float the to the right of the enclosing element.

Make sure to also set the "height" property for ".boxLogin" in your CSS.